# Burn subtitles into hls stream

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, video.js

I am trying to get a fragmented hls video with subtitles burned into video stream, but it is creating separate vtt files. I need the subtitles burned into the video itself, what am I doing wrong?

```
ffmpeg -y \
  -i input.mkv \
  -vf subtitles=input.mkv\
  -force_key_frames "expr:gte(t,n_forced*2)" \
  -sc_threshold 0 \
  -s 1280x720 \
  -c:v libx264 -b:v 4000k \
  -c:a copy \
  -hls_time 6 \
  -hls_playlist_type vod \
  -hls_segment_type fmp4 \
  -hls_segment_filename "fileSequence%d.m4s" \
  index.m3u8
```

Comment: Show the complete log from your command.

Comment: @llogan yes sure here it is
https://pastebin.com/1QJE08AC

Comment: a shot in the dark:  lack of symmetry indicates you may need a space character in front of the backslash on the '-vf' parameter line ???  Also, try putting double-quotes around that parameter.